# how does append works with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t=int(input())
#c=[i for i in range(t)]
for i in range(t):

    n=int(input())
    a = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    b = list()

    for i in range(n):
        if(a[i]==1):
            b.append(i)


    print(b)
```

when list a is (1 0 1) , list b is( 0,2 )
when list a is 1 0 0 1 , list b is  0 ,3 
In fact , I suppose the output of list b is ( 1,1) instead of  0, 2 since its definition is to add the obj into list 
Please tell me if there's something I miss or get wrong , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append `i`, which is the index, and not `a[i]` which is the value from `a`.

so `b` is essentially a list containing all indexes of elements in `a` that are equal `1`

Comment: wow! is that mean list b = [ i ,i i ] , then no sum of value appears  . However , why 0 appears in the beginning of the list ?

Comment: @JamesLo because `a[0]==1`